# windows 8.1 remove user data

Tags: windows, user-accounts, reset

I have 4 computers (Windows 8.1) that will be used for education purposes, smth. like one week courses. I created an user account that students will be using. What would be the easiest way to manage the privilages and delete all user data after the end of the course so new students can use them and not see any documents in user folders. The computers are not inside the domain.

Thank you

best regards

Comment: Removing user profile including user folder removes all ducuments created by it. Then re-create the profile - without documents...

Comment: any reboot to restore options that are "build in" windows 8.1